# Are there any platforms whose native `vi` is not vim, nvi, or original vi?

Tags: history-of

Just like in the title. I know most Linux distributions ship with vim and most BSDs use nvi, but I was wondering if there are any "obscure" versions of vi on some commercial UNIX or other platform, with their own extended commands that are not covered by the POSIX standard. Or, for that matter, any platforms that use some other vi clone (Elvis, Vile, etc) for the purpose.

Comment: This effectively just asks for a list of platforms and their default Vi flavours. I don't think this is a very good question for the SE format to be honest...

Comment: I'm asking about the existence of other vi flavors other than the most well known ones.

Answer (score 2):

Elvis is the default vi that ships with Slackware, Frugalware, KateOS, and MINIX 3.

Source:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_(text_editor)